# Swift 2.1 : Getting error while extends NSObject

Tags: swift2, nsobject, xcode7.2

I had created the sample application for testing the failable initializers. When I extends the NSObject then I am getting the below error.

> 1) Property 'self.userName' not initialized at super.init call. 
>  2)
>   Immutable value 'self.userDetails' may only be initialized once.
>  3)
>   Immutable value 'self.userName' may only be initialized once.

Please find the below code and screenshot for the same.

```
class User: NSObject {

    let userName: String!
    let userDetails: [String]?

    init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
        super.init()

        if let value = dictionary["user_name"] as? String {
            self.userName = value
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }

        self.userDetails = dictionary["user_Details"] as? Array
    }        
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All properties must initialised before `super.init()`

Nil must be returned from the failable initialiser after `super.init()`. This restriction [should be removed in Swift 2.2](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-18-a/CHANGELOG.md)

Correct implementation would be:

```
class User: NSObject {

    let userName: String!
    let userDetails: [String]?

    init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
        if let value = dictionary["user_name"] as? String {
            self.userName = value
        } else {
            self.userName = nil
        }

        self.userDetails = dictionary["user_Details"] as? Array

        super.init()

        if userName == nil {
            return nil
        }

        else if userDetails == nil {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give the link which stated that failable initialiser is removed from swift 2.2?

Comment: in 2.2 will be removed not bailable initialiser but second restriction

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

let dictionary = ["user_name": "user", "user_Details":[1,2,3]]

class User: NSObject {

    var userName: String?
    var userDetails: [String]?

    init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
        super.init()
        if let value = dictionary["user_name"] as? String {
            self.userName = value
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }

        self.userDetails = dictionary["user_Details"] as? Array
    }        
}

let c = User(dictionary: dictionary)
dump(c)
/*
▿ User
  ▿ Some: User #0
    - super: <__lldb_expr_31.User: 0x7fe372f15860>
    ▿ userName: user
      - Some: user
    - userDetails: nil
*/
```